# I wanna call button equals to array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom

I have 3 buttons in html(all of them has same class Name) and an array of length 3..
soo i want to call data in first index when i clicked first button.
and call data in second index when i clicked second button.

and here my code:

```
const infoBTN = document.getElementsByClassName('infoBTN')
const arr = [{name: 'Rawand'} , {name: 'Jack'} , {name: 'Max'}] ;

let num = 0;

const getInfo = function (){
  console.log(arr[num]); 
}

for(let i = 0 ; i<infoBTN.length ; i++){
  num = i;
  console.log('i = ' + i + ' And num = ' + num)
  infoBTN[i].addEventListener('click' , getInfo)
}
```

### Please Help Me Please

Comment: as far as i understand your question, you should just pass the `i` as a param and get the `arr` from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `getInfo` function *inside* the loop, so it can have a closure over the `i` index:

```js
const infoBTN = document.getElementsByClassName('infoBTN')
const arr = [{name: 'Rawand'} , {name: 'Jack'} , {name: 'Max'}] ;

for(let i = 0 ; i<infoBTN.length ; i++){
  infoBTN[i].addEventListener('click' , () => console.log(arr[i].name));
}
```

```html
<button class="infoBTN">click</button>
<button class="infoBTN">click</button>
<button class="infoBTN">click</button>
```

Comment: Ah its not work, its bring me undefined when i click second and third button

Comment: Works just fine here - press "Run code snippet". If you press the 2nd button, `Max` comes up. If you press the 3rd button, `Rawand` comes up.